# Pandas plot subplots of a 'group by' result

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, pandas

I struggle with my (poor) Pandas knowledge, as I try to get a bar plot on a hierachial index by a group by operation.

My data look like this

```
id, val, cat1, cat2
```

Then I create a hierachical index:

```
df_group = df_len.groupby(['cat1','cat2'])
```

I would like to get a **hbar plot** per cat1 object that lists all cat2 objects that lists the values of all cat1 objects within.

None of my approaches worked:

- `df_group.plot(...)`
- `for name, group in df_group: .... group.plot(...)`
- `df_group.xs(...)` experiments

The result should look somewhat like this one 
[image]

I guess I just lack of knowledge of `pandas`, `matplotlib`, ... -internals and it's not that difficult to plot a few 100 items (cat2<10, cat1=30)

.

Answer (score 2):

I'd recommend using [seaborn](http://web.stanford.edu/~mwaskom/software/seaborn/tutorial/categorical_linear_models.html) to do this type of faceted plot. Doing it in matplotlib is very tricky as the library is quite low level. Seaborn excels at this use case.

Comment: I tried seaborn, but without any luck in my case. But it seems to be a nice piece of code for higher dim data :)

Answer (score 2):

Ok guys, so here it's how I solved it finally:

```
dfc = df_len.groupby(['cat1','cat2']).count().reset_index()
dfp=dfc.pivot(index="cat1",columns="cat2")
dfp.columns = dfp.columns.get_level_values(1)
dfp.plot(kind='bar', figsize=(15, 5), stacked=True);
```

In short: I used a pivot table to transpose my matrix and then I was able to plot the single cols automaticly, at [example 2 here](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/visualization.html#bar-plots).

Answer (score 1):

Not so tricky in `matplotlib`, see:

```
In [54]:

print df
  cat1  cat2       val
0    A     1  0.011887
1    A     2  0.880121
2    A     3  0.034244
3    A     4  0.530230
4    B     1  0.510812
5    B     2  0.405322
6    B     3  0.406259
7    B     4  0.406405
In [55]:

col_list = ['r', 'g']
ax = plt.subplot(111)
for (idx, (grp, val)) in enumerate(df.groupby('cat1')):
    ax.bar(val.cat2+0.25*idx-0.25, 
           val.val, width=0.25,  
           color=col_list[idx], 
           label=grp)
plt.legend()
```

[image]

Comment: Nice idea, but I solved it finally with pure pandas and avoided the matplot tricks. But anyway, thanks for your help!